# Fire event when marquee completes

Tags: android, textview

I want to marquee text, and when the marquee completes (the 1 full marquee cycle), I want to trigger another event. Is there a good way to do this? I haven't seen an OnEnd or similar function when marquee-ing a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a custom `TextView`, you can override `onDraw` to use reflection on `mMarquee` field and on `mStatus` field of the `mMarquee` field (see TextView code on grepcode or such).

`mStatus` value is 2 when marquee is running, and 0 when stopped.

`onDraw` is called a lot, but in particular, it is called right after the marquee is completed.

Comment: How can you get this mMarquee field? I have seen  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

but I don't know how to get it work

Comment: hi @njzk2. Can you share example on how to use reflection on getting mMarquee. I am having issue getting this field or inherited fields. Thanks

Comment: @donmj see https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-class-fields to get started on reflection