# Is string shown in marquee textview is ended in android?

Tags: android, textview, marquee

IS there a method or any logic to check if a string being shown in marquee is ended or ended? I need to show another string which comes from webservice and changes every 30 seconds. So as one string ends i need to call webservice and show another string right after first string ends..... What should i do? Please help . I need this urgently. Thank you all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fire event when marquee completes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392540/fire-event-when-marquee-completes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please learn this from following Stack overflow answers:

[How to reverse the direction of marquee of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview)

and

[Fire event when marquee completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392540/fire-event-when-marquee-completes)